# SQLAlchemy get list of ids from a query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How do I get a list of ids instead of a list of SQLAlchemy objects? 
Currently I'm doing this:

```
[x.id for x in random_query.all()]
```

Is there a better way of doing this, preferably by only using SQLAlchemy statements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

SQL

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `id` FROM `table`;
```

Python

```
 for value in Session.query(Table.id).distinct():
     #Do something Append
```

Comment: What exactly is the difference between `[x.id for x in random_query.all()]` and `[x.id for x in random_query.distinct()]`?

Comment: `query(Table.id).distinct()` is what you are looking for. .distinct() does returns results that are only distinct by using the SQL statement that I have above. If your id column is defined as the primary key then it is by distinct by definition. However if it is not then .all() might return multiple id's more than once.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that works. Only problem I have is that it returns a list of tuples with only the id in there.

Comment: @JelteF `for value, in session.query(Table.id).distinct():` should fix that.

Answer (score 7):

Trying to be as accurate as possible to the original question, you **get a list of ids instead of a list of SQLAlchemy objects** by uing `with_entities()`

```
User.query.with_entities(User.id).all()
```

Think of it as, instead of doing a full select..

```
SELECT * FROM user
```

you are selecting only whatever field(s) you are interested in:

```
SELECT id FROM user
```

To be honest, what you get is a list of 1 element tuples:

```
[(7,), (11,), (15,), (21,), (37,)]
```

So **the final answer is**:

```
ids = [id[0] for id in User.query.with_entities(User.id).all()]
```

Comment: Note that you only need `with_entities` because you're using flask-sqlalchemy, which automagically maps the the model class into the query.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Good point! I didnt know this was only available for flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 7):

SQLAlchemy `Session` has method [scalars](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html?highlight=scalars#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.scalars) for getting list of values without mapping.

```
SQLAlchemy 1.4+ style:
results = Session.scalars(select(Table.id)).all()
```

SQLAlchemy old styles:

```
results = Session.scalars(Session.query(Table.id)).all()
results = Session.scalars(Table.query.with_entities(Table.id)).all()
```

Actual `results`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
session.query(Thing.id).all()
```

usually you query for whole objects but you can query for attributes too

Answer (score 2):

Using SQLAlchemy 1.4+, you can you use the [core-style select syntax](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/data_select.html#selecting-rows-with-core-or-orm):

```py
ids = session.execute(select(MyModel.spam).distinct()).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the list I got back, was in the form of a tuple, so I found it useful to do something like this. I used the classes that came straight out of SQLACODEGEN and unfortunately it uses some sort of generic Numeric that returns floats too, hence the casting.

```
ids = list(map(lambda x: int(x[0]), \   
session.query(Trgmst.trgmst_id).filter(Trgmst.trgmst_trigger==trigger).all()))
```

I was originally thinking of doing something like this in my case..

```
ids = list(map(lambda x: int(x[0]), \
session.query(Trgmst.trgmst_id).filter(Trgmst.trgmst_trigger==trigger).all()))
return session.query(Trgjob).filter( \
    and_(Trgjob.jobmst_id==jobmst_id, Trgjob.trgmst_id.in_(ids)) \
    ).count() > 0
```

But in the end went with this instead:

```
return session.query(Trgjob).join(Trgjob.trgmst). \
    filter(Trgjob.jobmst_id==jobmst_id). \
    filter(Trgmst.trgmst_trigger==trigger). \
    count() > 0
```

This was because I was filtering on an attribute of a joined file.

`trgmst` is the relationship to `Trgmst` from `Trgjob`.